# TeamCity 9.1.4 can't add snapshot dependency

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am unable to add a snapshot dependency.

[image: Step 1]

After Clicking Save:

[image: Step 2]

A weird XML page appears (seems like an error to be displayed on the previous form).

This means that I actually can't add a snapshot dependency.

No matter what settings on the form I try I get the same issue.

I've tried restoring from a backup and reinstalling. I've only ever used the latest version 9.1.4 (build 37293).

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this? Or how I can manually add this in config files?

Comment: Do the project that you depend on been build (at least once)? I had that problem that I was not able to make the dependency before I had been running the build on once on the project I try to depend on.

Comment: Hey, The project will build correctly and I still get the same issue.